# Unexpected behavior of .loc on multilevel indexed dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I encountered a behavior of .loc for dataframes with a mulitlevel index, that I can't explain.

The setup:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'DT': [2018, 2018, 2017, 2018],
                   'F1': [0, 1, 0, 0],
                   'F2': [0, 0, 1, 0]  })

df.loc[5]= [5, 2019, 1, 0]
df
```

Up to now everythings nice and looks like (note a line with index 5 has been inserted):

```
   ID    DT  F1  F2
0   1  2018   0   0
1   2  2018   1   0
2   3  2017   0   1
3   4  2018   0   0
5   5  2019   1   0
```

Now create a copy with a mulilevel index on 'ID' and 'DT' and use it with loc:

```
indexed= df.set_index(['ID', 'DT'], inplace=False)
indexed.loc[(2, 2018)]
```

This still works and outputs the values corresponding to the given index values:

```
F1    1
F2    0
Name: (2, 2018), dtype: int64
```

It also can be updated this way using:

```
indexed.loc[(2, 2018)]= [1, 4]
```

Now try to insert a new row the same way we could do it above on the single level index:

```
indexed.loc[(1, 2019)]= [3, 4]
```

This raises an exception:

```
ValueError: cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length than the value
```

And the dataframe was changed, as if the loc access interpreted 2019 to be the name of a column. So the dataframe now looks like:

```
         F1  F2  2019
ID DT                
1  2018   0   0   NaN
2  2018   1   0   NaN
3  2017   0   1   NaN
4  2018   0   0   NaN
5  2019   1   0   NaN
```

Can anybody explain this strange behavior, or is that a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:` for get all columns for new or update, without `:` it is shorcut, unfortunately working only for update:

```
indexed.loc[(2, 2018), :]= [1, 4]
indexed.loc[(1, 2019), :]= [3, 4]
print (indexed)
          F1   F2
ID DT            
1  2018  0.0  0.0
2  2018  1.0  4.0
3  2017  0.0  1.0
4  2018  0.0  0.0
5  2019  1.0  0.0
1  2019  3.0  4.0
```

Comment: Thank you. The difference is still a bit strange, but I noticed, that [] (the '__getitem__' method) get's the same object if called with df[1,2] as if it is called df[(1,2)] because python implicitely creates tuples, that's what I didn't have in mind.

Comment: Hmm, I thought about it a second time. The point is, that pandas obviously treats the argument to getitem different as the argument to setitem and this is counter-intuitive. So your answer is a good workaround, but I guess the observed behavior is still a bug.

Comment: @jottbe -  I agree, I think the best is create new issue [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues).